# Find records that qualify as pairs

Tags: sql, join

I have a sql database which looks like this:

[image]

I want to get all `EAN`s (european article number, it's like a sku) where `stock_level` is `Null`, and which have a duplicate" (where duplicate means same `style`, `color` and `size`)

So the red cells represent this kind of "duplicate" pair, so `EAN` `400006` would be what I want to output and later delete.

Knowing how I can group and count, I still can't figure out a way to isolate the `EAN`s.

Comment: BTW: the `stock_level` should be zero, not `NULL` if there is no stock.

Comment: Agreed. Thats because I joined the products table with the inventory table, and those products are not existent in the inventory table. Basically meaning they are not in the warehouse and the records can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select *
from eans t
where stock_level is null and
      exists (select 1
              from eans t2
              where t2.style = t.style and
                    t2.color = t.color and
                    t2.size = t.size and
                    t2.stock_level is not null
             );
```

I'm assuming that you want to duplicate to have a non-NULL `stock_level`, as in your example.

Comment: What is my actual table? t or t2? In the sqlite db the table is called "eans"

Comment: Wow thanks @Notulysses for taking the time to create the fiddle! That helped me much!!!

Comment: @Notulysses: I tried this with my db, sorry I forgot to mention that its a sqlite3 db. Does the query work with this as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.EAN 
FROM `table` t JOIN ( SELECT style
                           , color
                           , size  
                      FROM `table` 
                      GROUP BY style
                             , color
                             , size 
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                    ) x ON t.style = x.style 
                       AND t.color = x.color 
                       AND t.size = x.size
WHERE t.stock_level IS NULL ;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fccc7/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TheTable where 
(style, color, size) IN
(
select style, color, size from TheTable
Group by style, color, size
Having count(*) > 1
)
and stock_level is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like below

```
SELECT A.EAN FROM yourtable A 
INNER JOIN yourtable B 
on A.style=B.style AND A.color=B.color AND A.size=B.size
AND A.stock_level IS NULL 
GROUP BY A.EAN having count(A.EAN)>1
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48542/7/0)